# maven-compiler-pulgin error while importing broadleaf project

Tags: maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e, broadleaf-commerce

[image]I am trying to use the [broadleaf](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started) So, I was following the "Get Started" instructions . I have integrated maven as described in the website. But i am facing the error like in the image. I do not know how to solve this error as I am new to both broadleaf and maven. Please suggest me a way to run the sample project given in the website.

- Eclipse Version - Kepler Service Release 2
- Maven Version - 1.4.0.20130601-0317
- JDK - 1.7.0_03

I will provide more information if you required any. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

These errors can be safely ignored. This is simply Eclipse being dumb.

Once you get the project imported, you can mark them as ignored in your Eclipse preferences (hover over the error in the pom.xml and choose that option to resolve the issue).

Comment: I have imported the prject. But it is showing errors wothout hinting how to resolve them..  CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
  2.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.0.2: ArtifactResolutionException: